# Getting a "Error while creating file "/target"" when deploying a JHipster project onto Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, jhipster, h2

I am trying to deploy my Jhipster (v5.5.0) project onto Kubernetes (v1.16.3), but the pod keeps failing with the below logs. Anyone have any ideas?

Here is my YAML that will create the deployment / pod. I have another YAML that creates the PV and PVC.

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: portal
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: portal
          image: "portal"
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "0.5"
              memory: "2048Mi"
            requests:
              cpu: "0.1"
              memory: "64Mi"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          workingDir: /
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 950
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
        - name: portal-db-vol01
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: portal-db-pvc-volume01
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 15
```

Below are my logs:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Error while creating file "/target" [90062-196]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
        at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.createDirectory(FilePathDisk.java:274)
....

2020-02-05T21:59:14Z  WARN 7 - [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulConfiguration$ZuulFilterConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'filters'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'noCachePreFilter' defined in URL [jar:file:/app.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/com/odp/filters/pre/NoCachePreFilter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#248deced' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#248deced': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/odp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Error while creating file "/target" [90062-196]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the container `portal` in pod run as non-root `950`

```
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 950
```

Please confirm if this user has permission to create a file/folder in root `/`. Normally only root has this permission. The only writable folders for non-root users are under:

```
Home directory (~/)
/tmp
/var/tmp
```

Comment: I changed it to this, and now it works. But what do I need to change to keep the original “non-root”, while still getting this to work? Maybe I put in a bash command into the k8s deployment, to do “chmod 777 /target”?
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: false
            runAsUser: 0

Comment: when you build the docker image, you should make sure the user has been created and set write permission on some folders to that user already.